# using switch case login and new user registration in php

Tags: php, forms, switch-statement

I tried to work on with switch case login and newuser submit button, but i get only default case option with its values. and below is the code.

```
<?php
    switch ($_POST['submit'])
    {
        //Customer Logins here 
        case "CLogin":
            $var1 = $_POST['cname'];
            $var2 = $_POST['cpwd'];

            $con1 = mysql_connect("localhost","FreeUser","123456");
            if(!$con1){
                die('Could not Connect to mySql server : ' . mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                mysql_select_db("ecommerce",$con1);
                $r1 = mysql_query("select username,password from newusers where username='$var1' and         password='$var2'");
                while($som = mysql_fetch_row($r1)){
                    $tn = $som[0];
                    $tp = $som[1];
                }

                if($tn == $var1 && $tp == $var2)
                {
                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION['LoggedUser']= $var1;
                }
                else{echo "Please check Username & Password again!";}
            }
        break;


        //New Customer Sign up here
        case "CNewUser":

        break;


        //Wrong opotion code here
        default :
            echo "check out";
            echo $_POST['cuname'];
            echo $_POST['cpwd'];
            break;
    }
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" >
    <table>
        <tr><td>User Id : </td><td><input type="text" name="cuname" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password : </td><td><input type="password" name="cpwd" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="CLogin" value="Sign In"><input type="submit" name="CNewUser" value="New User"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$_POST['submit']` with `$_POST['CLogin']`. And case-values should be equal to `input` value, so you are now receiving: `$_POST['CLogin'] => 'Sign In'`.

The rule of thumb: `$_POST` keys are `name` of inputs, values are `value` of inputs

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['submit'] is no field in your form. It's either $_POST['CLogin'] or $_POST['CNewUser'] that is set. What you could do is give both submit buttons the same name and check for different values.

So for inputs with name 'submit' and Values 'Login' and 'New User', you'd get:

```
switch ($_POST['submit'])
{
  case 'Login':
    // Code here
  break;
  case 'New User':
    // Code here
  break;
  default:
    // Code here
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have a `$_POST['submit']` as your `submit` is actually `CLogin` or `CNewUser`
2. You should try:

   ```
   switch ($_POST['submit']){
       case 'Sign In':
       .....
       case 'New User':
       .....
   }

   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="New User"></td>
   ```